# How do I use custom user forms?

Tags: forms, users, 8

After creating separate user registration form in *Structure > Display Modes > Form Mode* and creating those forms in *Configuration > People > Manage Forms*, how do I use these forms? I want different roles on my site to use different registration forms to register different users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option for this in ui.

You have to define the display mode for the form in mymodule.routing.yml:

**Example from user.routing.yml**

```
user.admin_create:
  path: '/admin/people/create'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'user.register'
    _title: 'Add user'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer users'
```

In the line  `_entity_form: 'user.register'` the form is `user` and the form mode is `register`.

Then you can access the form with the path defined here and restrict the access through roles with requirements.

**Edit (place the form on any page)**

If you want to place the form on any page, you need the form as a block.

You can use this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform_block

But it does not have the option for arguments like form mode.

This experimental module can do this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_forms_in_blocks

> - Interesting features that does not exists for now with the other modules : ability to choose the form mode as Drupal 8 allows to (in
>     Drupal 8, you can create additional form modes).

Comment: I created the forms in display modes as I mentioned in the question already. I have not created any custom module. In drupal 7, we could render a form with `drupal_get_form` and I know we can use form builder to render any form on anypage. I am not sure the class i should pass in the arguments though.

Comment: In this case you don't need a path for the form, but you need the form as a block, see the edited answer.

Comment: Very great module - entity_forms_in_block. One problem still though, can it render different user registration forms for different pages?

Comment: You have to configure the visibility of each block in block layout.